# ffmpeg: Possible to combine two "bad" TS files to get one good (or better) one?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to use two over-the-air TS recordings of the same show (same resolution, either from two stations airing it at the same time, or the same station airing it at different times) as inputs, so that when there is an error in one input, it will try to "borrow" data from the other input?

I realize the commercial breaks could have different content, but I don't care if commercials get trashed.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no.

Long answer, yes, but not really...

But let me explain. The problem is that our human brains are really good at doing very complex tasks. We see when something is an error, but things like ffmpg just doesn't know what is considered an error and what isn't, so it can't distinguish bad from good frames.

So you would have to manually look at each frame and select which of the two is better, or even better, get the best parts of each frame and stitch it together. That is actually doable, but that would also mean that you would be working for a few years on one tv episode of 45 minutes, because it is that labor intensive. By the time you are finished, you don't even need to see that episode anymore, given that you seen it inside out. Oh, and syncing the audio to the image is another story...

Some may say that you can find the errors by the use of filters, but even so, you don't know what is correct once you get to the errors themselves.

Comment: “it can't distinguish bad from good frames” — that's not correct. When streaming over unreliable protocol stacks such as MPEG-TS/RTP/UDP, frames or parts of frames (slices) can get lost. ffmpeg can recognize that while decoding, since the encoded video bitstream has to conform to a certain syntax and you'll notice when that's not the case. Up to a certain extent, lost slices can even be repaired (error concealment) by copying macroblocks over. These could, in theory, come from another instance of the stream, although you'd of course need a buffer, and the packets would have to be linkable.

Comment: I'm not saying it's easy, but the problem is not that you wouldn't find out where the errors are, or which of the frames is worse when comparing A/B. The complexity lies in matching the recordings.